# Websocket, SecurityError on IE 11 after some time of usage

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, websocket, internet-explorer-11

We have a library which connects to the webSocket server running on the PC from the web socket client inside a web page with standard javascript webSocket client. The web page is running on https and our webSocket communication is with wss on localhost.

After some time (2 minutes and more) we are getting the Security error, when we want to communicate with the webSocket server. In the console also appear

> the Max Session timeout settings updated from iframe:..

as I attached below. I've attached the error and the log from the console. We are using Internet explorer 11.

```
Max Session timeout settings updated from iframe:  https://.......lcid=1033&themeId=ccf5c90e-e435-e911-a847-000d3a20dff2&tstamp=2851759&updateTimeStamp=636903320640637959&userts=132012737777621646&ver=-1083510705#etc=1&extraqs=%3f_gridType%3d1%26etc%3d1%26id%3d%257b58CABECA-6167-E911-A2EB-00505636AC47%257d%26rskey%3d%257b00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001002%257d&pagemode=iframe&pagetype=entityrecord&rskey=%7b00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001002%7d&counter=1556802020518
SecurityError
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 18,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SecurityError",
      name: "SecurityError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      Symbol(observable)_y.49yp6wheckl: undefined,
      Symbol(react.async_mode)_x.49yp6wheckl: undefined,
      Symbol(react.concurrent_mode)_s.49yp6whecxl: undefined,
      Symbol(react.context)_r.49yp6whecxl: undefined,
      Symbol(react.element)_l.49yp6whecxl: undefined,
      Symbol(react.forward_ref)_t.49yp6whecxl: undefined,
      Symbol(react.fragment)_n.49yp6whecxl: undefined,
      Symbol(react.lazy)_w.49yp6wheckl: undefined,
      Symbol(react.memo)_v.49yp6whecxl: undefined,
      Symbol(react.portal)_m.49yp6whecxl: undefined,
      Symbol(react.profiler)_p.49yp6whecxl: undefined,
      Symbol(react.provider)_q.49yp6whecxl: undefined,
      Symbol(react.strict_mode)_o.49yp6whecxl: undefined,
      Symbol(react.suspense)_u.49yp6whecxl: undefined,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

SCRIPT5022: SecurityError
identificationVendor.js (41,97351)
```

The connection is open for the whole time (we didn't close and open webSocket communication again when we need it). Pushing F5 doesn't help after error. What only helps is close the tab and run it again in another tab or restart IE.

Any idea what can be a problem or how to find the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Does it only happen in IE? Did you want to modify the session timeout property in your code? can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Were you able to figure out this issue.

Comment: After some time this problem disappears. Our sofware was integrated to the 3rd party solution and it seems that maybe changing the session timeout or something like that